# Constrain direction with linear programming (simplex)

Tags: java, 2d, linear-algebra, game-physics

I want to make a modular 2D spaceship game. The user can use building blocks to create the ship. Blocks can be squares but also other shapes that do not fit in a grid. To calculate what thrusters should be firing with user input I use [ojAlgo](http://ojalgo.org/) to solve a linear programming problem. The user input will be something like: [x: 1, y: 0, z 0] where a 1 is the maximum thrust that can be given in the direction and -1 the same to the other side. Z is rotation here.

I have two problems:
The first has to do with the way I calculate x and y separate:

```
final ExpressionsBasedModel tmpModel = new ExpressionsBasedModel();
final Expression expressionX = tmpModel.addExpression("x").weight(1); //This is the user input.
final Expression expressionY = tmpModel.addExpression("y").weight(0).level(0); //Level means lower == 0 and upper == 0
final Expression expressionZ = tmpModel.addExpression("z").weight(0).level(0);

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    ThrusterBlock thrusterBlock = blockStash.thrusterList.get(i);
    final Variable thrusterVar = Variable.make("th_" + i);
    thrusterVar.lower(0).upper(1);
    tmpModel.addVariable(thrusterVar);

    expressionX.setLinearFactor(thrusterVar, thrusterBlock.displacement.x);
    expressionY.setLinearFactor(thrusterVar, thrusterBlock.displacement.y);
    expressionZ.setLinearFactor(thrusterVar, thrusterBlock.displacement.z); 
    //The thruster displacement is the calculated thrust in the given direction
}

Optimisation.Result tmpResult = tmpModel.maximise(); //To get the maximum weight (& thrust) out.
```

This works because i can set the weight to > 0 or < 0 and it will return for each thruster a value between 0 and 1. With a layout with 9 thrusters this could be a output:

```
OPTIMAL 1.203 @ [1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.32, 0.32, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
[
    0th [x: 0.401, y: 0.0 , z: -0.022]
    1th [x: 0.401, y: 0.0 , z: -0.022]
    2th [x: -0.401, y: 0.0 , z: -0.027]
    3th [x: -0.401, y: 0.0 , z: -0.027]
    4th [x: 0.0, y: 0.401 , z: 0.025]
    5th [x: 0.0, y: -0.401 , z: 0.025]
    6th [x: 0.0, y: -0.401 , z: 0.025]
    7th [x: 0.0, y: 0.401 , z: 0.025]
    8th [x: 0.401, y: 0.0 , z: -0.022]
]
```

The problem is that i can't use this system to move diagonally (e.g. 40°) because

```
final Expression expressionX = tmpModel.addExpression("x").weight(1);
final Expression expressionY = tmpModel.addExpression("y").weight(1);
```

Won't constrain the equation to a 1:1 x & y ratio but find the most rewarding solution. I can't use level here because i don't know the max thrust for both.
What would be the best way to constrain x & y so that i can use degrees?

The second question:
When i want the ship to turn, it does so about 45° and then turns back. While the control system shows that the same thrusters are firing. I am sure there is a problem with the way i calculate the force but my experience with angle calculations is low. I think the mistake can be found here:

```
public Vector2 getForce(float power, boolean relative){
   float force = maxThrust * power;
   float angle = toRad(this.relativePosition.z) + (relative ? 0 : this.blockCluster.getPos().z);
   //relativePosition.z is the orientation of the block in degree and this.blockCluster.getPos().z is the ship rotation in radians
   temp.x = force * ((float) Math.cos(angle)) * -1;
   temp.y = force * ((float) Math.sin(angle));
   return temp;
}
```

I think it has something to do with Cosines and Sinus returning only 90° but i am not sure.

Lastly, any optimisation would be greatly appreciated since this might run for multiple frames in a row. I will save the results of the calculation if it is on the slow side.

Thanks for your time!

ps: Ported from 'Game Development' because the implementation is more general then the use case.

Comment: ... but why do you need a maximization solver to calculate thruster levels on a *2D* platform?

Comment: I would love a easier way to do so but I would like to simulate more than just thruster on/of action. Besides its easy to look for thruster pairs that counter in rotation but I also want non-symmetrical designs.  

EDIT 
I also wouldn't mind *not* maximising as long as it moves in the correct direction with a reasonable speed (Depending on the thruster output in that direction)